# Como escrever comandos em um programa console através de um arquivo batch (.bat)?

Tags: windows, batch, linha-de-comando

Quero automatizar uma rotina através de uma `.bat` que chame um programa console que, por sua vez, receberá comandos sucessivos a partir desta `.bat`. Este programa console poderia ser, por exemplo, um client ftp.

Exemplo:

```
c:> BaixarArquivo.bat MeuArquivo.ext
```

Conteúdo `BaixarArquivo.bat`:

```
cd /d c:\DiretorioDescarga
ftp 111.222.333.444
ftp> mget %0       // Como fazer um 'output' destes
ftp> quit          //  comandos dentro da .bat?
```

Considerando que a .bat irá aguardar o término da chamada do programa, como fazer para repassar esses comandos ao mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode direcionar os inputs da seguinte maneira:

```
(
echo mget %0
echo quit
) | ftp 111.222.333.444
```

No entanto, consulte a documentação do seu programa se ele permite alguns parâmetros de execução. Pode ser que ele aceite uma lista de comandos a serem executados.

Comment: Na mosca! Era disso que eu precisava.

Answer (score 5):

Para passar parâmetros pra um `.bat`:

```
echo off
echo %1
```

No código acima eu passei o número do parâmetro que eu quero pegar, no caso vai ser apenas 1:

`programa.bat argumento`

Você pode usar também o coringa: `%*` que ele pega todos os parâmetros que forem passados separados por espaço.

Para guardar o retorno de algum comando você pode criar uma variável:
`set arg = retorno`

Comment: Me desculpe pela má interpretação da pergunta. Por algum motivo alguém alterou o título deste tópico, mudando o seu sentido original.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa disso.
Você está usando o ftp.exe do próprio Windows, certo?

```
Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuffer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

  -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.
  -n              Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
  -i              Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file
                  transfers.
  -d              Enables debugging.
  -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
  -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.
  -A              login as anonymous.
  -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.
  -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.
  -b:async count  Overrides the default async count of 3
  -w:windowsize   Overrides the default transfer buffer size of 65535.
  host            Specifies the host name or IP address of the remote
                  host to connect to.

Notes:
  - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
  - Use Control-C to abort commands.
```

Preste atenção na opção -s que te permite especificar um arquivo com os comandos que deverão ser executados assim que o programa for executado.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
ftp.exe -s:comandos.txt
```

**Conteúdo do arquivo comandos.txt**

```
open dominio.com.br
usuario
senha
quit
```

Se for o caso, basta você editar o comandos.txt para que ele se adapte a suas necessidades com o nome do arquivo que você quer enviar ou receber.
Te permitindo maior controle sobre as operações que você vai realizar no FTP.

Comment: No meu caso, preciso sim. O ftp é somente um exemplo para simplificar minhar pergunta. No meu caso real, irei fazer consultas SQL através de um client Oracle, retornar resultados, e outras coisas mais...